# Makefile execute script for every file in folder

Tags: makefile

i want to execute for every .sh file a shell script that convert a .sh script into .md file.
At the moment i got this output from makefile

```
'./myscript' < testB.sh testA.sh >> testB.md testA.md
```

but i want an output like this

```
'./myscript' < testA.sh >> testA.md; './shelltomd' < testB.sh >> testB.md
```

i want to do this without any form of loop but i dont know how to solve this with makefile only :/

my Makefile

```
SH_FILES=$(wildcard *.sh)
SHTOMD=$(SH_FILES:.sh=.md)
md:
'./myscript' <$< $(SH_FILES) >>$< $(SHTOMD)
```

thank you for your help stackoverflow community and sry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a single rule that knows how to turn one `.sh` file into one `.md` file.  You can use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) for that:

```
%.md : %.sh
        './myscript' < $< > $@
```

(I doubt you want to use `>>` here)

Once you have taught make how to create an .md file, just tell it which md files you want to create:

```
SH_FILES := $(wildcard *.sh)
MD_FILES := $(SH_FILES:.sh=.md)

md: $(MD_FILES)
```

and you're done.